# function with closure not working correctly

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

on my social app in swiftUI I'm using firebase as backend, unfortunately
I find out that sometimes the listener (I don't know why) download 2/3 time the same change, so with some stackOverflow help I came up with the following to function in order to listen the change and publish it on the view.

```
 func getuserConfirmFriend(userLoggato: UserModel, onSuccess: @escaping([UserModel]) -> Void, onError: @escaping(_ errorMessage: String) -> Void, newPendingUser: @escaping(UserModel) -> Void, userRemoved: @escaping(UserModel) -> Void , listener: @escaping(_ listenerHandle: ListenerRegistration) -> Void){
           let listenerRegistration = db.collection("user").document(userLoggato.userID).collection("confimFriend").addSnapshotListener(includeMetadataChanges: false) { documentSnapshot, error in
              var userConfirmFriendsArray = [UserModel]()
               guard let snapshot = documentSnapshot else { return }
               
               snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { (documentChange) in
                   switch documentChange.type {
                   case .added :
                       let dict = documentChange.document.data()
                       let name = dict["name"] as? String ?? "na name"
                       let surname = dict["surname"] as? String ?? "na name"
                       let email = dict["email"] as? String ?? "na name"
                       let userLevel = dict["adminLevel"] as? String ?? "unable to get admin level"
                       let idUser = dict["userID"] as? String ?? "no ID"
                       let position1 = dict["position"] as? String ?? "na preferance position"
                       let position2 = dict["position2"] as? String ?? "na preferance position"
                       let vote = dict["vote"] as? Int ?? 0
                       self.downloadImageForAdmin(userID: idUser) { (urlImage) in
                           let utente = UserModel(name: name, surname: surname, email: email, userID: idUser, adminLevel: userLevel, immagine: urlImage, position: position1, position2: position2, vote: vote)
                           
                           newPendingUser(utente)
                           userConfirmFriendsArray.append(utente)
                          // if I put onSuccess here it work but keep duplicating the result
                       }
                       print("CONFIRM User Added")
                   case .modified :
                       //implements action (new escaping)
                       
                       print("CONFIRM User Modified ")
                   case .removed :
                     print("CONFIRM User Removed")
                       let dict = documentChange.document.data()
                       let name = dict["name"] as? String ?? "na name"
                       let surname = dict["surname"] as? String ?? "na name"
                       let email = dict["email"] as? String ?? "na name"
                       let userLevel = dict["adminLevel"] as? String ?? "unable to get admin level"
                       let idUser = dict["userID"] as? String ?? "no ID"
                       let position1 = dict["position"] as? String ?? "na preferance position"
                       let position2 = dict["position2"] as? String ?? "na preferance position"
                       let vote = dict["vote"] as? Int ?? 0
                       self.downloadImageForAdmin(userID: idUser) { (urlImage) in
                           let utente = UserModel(name: name, surname: surname, email: email, userID: idUser, adminLevel: userLevel, immagine: urlImage, position: position1, position2: position2, vote: vote)
                           userRemoved(utente)
                       }
                   }
                   
                   
               }
               
              onSuccess(userConfirmFriendsArray)
 // Problem Here, not working this closure onSuccess
// Any reason why this closure always return an empty array?? should be filled on .added case
           }
           listener(listenerRegistration)
       }
```

the problem I'm finding is: by my small knowledge, the closure onSuccess should be put after the forEach.
Like this I can use the userConfirmFriendsArray:[UserModel] (see my comment on the code)
but looks like it always return an empty array, why??? if the case .added append the user inside
userConfirmFriendsArray.

here below how I use getuserConfirmFriend()

```
func loadUserConfirmFriends(userLoggato: UserModel){
        
        self.userConfirmFriends = []
//        self.isLoading = true
        
        getuserConfirmFriend(userLoggato: userLoggato, onSuccess: { (users) in
            if self.userConfirmFriends.count == 0 {
            self.userConfirmFriends = users
            }
//        self.isLoading = false
        },
                             
        onError: { (errorMessage) in
        print("Error Message \(errorMessage)")
        },
        
        newPendingUser: { (user) in
            if self.userConfirmFriends.count > 0 {
            self.userConfirmFriends.append(user)
            }
        }, userRemoved: {(userRemoved) in
            
            let index = self.userConfirmFriends.firstIndex { (user) -> Bool in
                
                userRemoved.userID == user.userID
            }
            if index == nil {
                return
            } else {
            if self.userConfirmFriends.count >= 1 {
                self.userConfirmFriends = []
            } else {
                self.userConfirmFriends.remove(at: index!)}}
        })
        { (listener) in
        self.listener = listener
        }
    }
```

in order to see the change I have to put the onSuccess(userConfirmFriendsArray) closure inside the case .added:, but why?? can't be put after the forEach? if I put there always gave me an empty array.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

because `snapshot.documentChanges.forEach` doing things and call their closure async in different thread

so when you call `onSuccess(userConfirmFriendsArray)` line after `snapshot.documentChanges.forEach` the closure not called yet

and you have `self.downloadImageForAdmin(userID: idUser)` that call the closure async in different thread too

you can read how [multithreading work](https://www.viget.com/articles/concurrency-multithreading-in-ios/)