# How to create subcollections with Firestore in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

As much as I understand the theory behind the subcollections and SwiftUI, I have a hard time applying it on code. The idea is to create a supplier which in turn has brands which in turns has models, colors, sizes, etc. I'm creating a patient/inventory management app and I copied the patient code (which I got a lot of help from @peterfriese) to the inventory one provided all I needed was to change a few lines to be able to enable a subcollections to create itself but I'm completely baffled. I have as much difficulty applying the code to the view as I do for viewModel. I also, for some reason, have encountered an issue with the saving an edit for my supplier which simply adds an entry instead of editing it. Here is my code.

SupplierListView

```
import SwiftUI


struct SupplierListView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = SupplierViewModel()
    @State private var presentAddNewSupplierScreen = false
    
    
    private var addButton: some View {
       Button(action: { self.presentAddNewSupplierScreen.toggle() }) {
         Image(systemName: "plus")
       }
     }
    
    private func supplierRowView(supplier: SupplierModel) -> some View {
       NavigationLink(destination: SupplierDetailView(supplier: supplier)) {
         VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(supplier.supplier ?? "")
             .font(.headline)
           
         }
       }
     }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                   ForEach (viewModel.suppliers) { supplier in
                     supplierRowView(supplier: supplier)
                   }
                   .onDelete() { indexSet in
                     viewModel.removeSuppliers(atOffsets: indexSet)
                   }
                 }
                 .navigationBarTitle("Suppliers")
                 .navigationBarItems(trailing: addButton)
                 .onAppear() {
                   print("SupplierListView appears. Subscribing to data updates.")
                   self.viewModel.subscribe()
                 }
                 .onDisappear() {
                   // By unsubscribing from the view model, we prevent updates coming in from
                   // Firestore to be reflected in the UI. Since we do want to receive updates
                   // when the user is on any of the child screens, we keep the subscription active!
                   //
                   // print("BooksListView disappears. Unsubscribing from data updates.")
                   // self.viewModel.unsubscribe()
                 }
                 .sheet(isPresented: self.$presentAddNewSupplierScreen) {
                   SupplierEditView()
                 }
               }
    }
}

struct SupplierListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SupplierListView()
    }
}
```

SupplierEditView

```
import SwiftUI

enum ModeSupplier {
  case new
  case edit
}

enum ActionSupplier {
  case delete
  case done
  case cancel
}

extension Optional where Wrapped == String {
    var _boundSupplier: String? {
        get {
            return self
        }
        set {
            self = newValue
        }
    }
    public var boundSupplier: String {
        get {
            return _boundSupplier ?? ""
        }
        set {
            _boundSupplier = newValue.isEmpty ? nil : newValue
        }
    }
}


struct SupplierEditView: View {
    
   @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @State var presentActionSheet = false

    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = SupplierDetailViewModel()
    var mode: Mode = .new
    var completionHandler: ((Result<Action, Error>) -> Void)?
    
    
    var cancelButton: some View {
      Button(action: { self.handleCancelTapped() }) {
        Text("Cancel")
      }
    }
    
    var saveButton: some View {
      Button(action: { self.handleDoneTapped() }) {
        Text(mode == .new ? "Done" : "Save")
      }
      .disabled(!viewModel.modified)
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Supplier Name")) {
                    TextField("Supplier Name", text: $viewModel.supplier.supplier.bound)
                }
                if mode == .edit {
                        Section {
                          Button("Delete Supplier") { self.presentActionSheet.toggle() }
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                        }
                      }
            }
        
        .navigationBarTitle("New Supplier", displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(mode == .new ? .inline : .large)

        .navigationBarItems(
            leading: cancelButton,
            trailing: saveButton
          )
            .actionSheet(isPresented: $presentActionSheet) {
                ActionSheet(title: Text("Are you sure?"),
                buttons: [
                .destructive(Text("Delete Supplier"),
                                action: { self.handleDeleteTapped() }),
                        .cancel()
                    ])
                }
        }
    }

func handleCancelTapped() {
    dismiss()
}

func handleDoneTapped(){
    viewModel.saveSupplier()
    dismiss()
}
    
func handleDeleteTapped() {
      viewModel.handleDeleteTapped()
      self.dismiss()
      self.completionHandler?(.success(.delete))
    }
    
func dismiss(){
    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
}

}

struct SupplierEditView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let supplier = SupplierModel(id: "", supplier: "")
        let supplierViewModel = SupplierDetailViewModel(supplier: supplier)
        return SupplierEditView(viewModel: supplierViewModel, mode: .edit)
    }
}
```

SupplierDetailView

```
import SwiftUI

struct SupplierDetailView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
     @State var presentEditSupplierSheet = false
     
     
     var supplier: SupplierModel
          
     private func editButton(action: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
       Button(action: { action() }) {
         Text("Edit")
       }
     }
    var body: some View {
        Form {
             Section(header: Text("Supplier Name")) {
                Text(supplier.supplier ?? "")
             }
           
           }
        .navigationBarTitle(supplier.supplier ?? "")
           .navigationBarItems(trailing: editButton {
             self.presentEditSupplierSheet.toggle()
           })
           .onAppear() {
             print("SupplierDetailView.onAppear() for \(self.supplier.supplier)")
           }
           .onDisappear() {
             print("SupplierDetailView.onDisappear()")
           }
           .sheet(isPresented: self.$presentEditSupplierSheet) {
             SupplierEditView(viewModel: SupplierDetailViewModel(supplier: supplier), mode: .edit) { result in
               if case .success(let action) = result, action == .delete {
                 self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
               }
             }
           }
         }
    }


struct SupplierDetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let supplier = SupplierModel(id: "", supplier: "")
        return
            NavigationView{
        SupplierDetailView(supplier: supplier)
            }
    }
}
```

SupplierModel

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct SupplierModel: Identifiable, Codable {
    @DocumentID var id : String? = UUID().uuidString
    var supplier: String?
}
```

SupplierModelView

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift


class SupplierViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var suppliers = [SupplierModel]()
    
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    private var listenerRegistration: ListenerRegistration?

    deinit {
        unsubscribe()
    }
    
    func unsubscribe() {
       if listenerRegistration != nil {
         listenerRegistration?.remove()
         listenerRegistration = nil
       }
     }
    
    
    func subscribe() {
        if listenerRegistration == nil {
            listenerRegistration = db.collection("suppliers").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("No suppliers")
                return
            }
            
            self.suppliers = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot -> SupplierModel? in
                return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: SupplierModel.self)
             
            }
        }
    }
}
    func removeSuppliers(atOffsets indexSet: IndexSet) {
       let suppliers = indexSet.lazy.map { self.suppliers[$0] }
       suppliers.forEach { supplier in
         if let documentId = supplier.id {
           db.collection("suppliers").document(documentId).delete { error in
             if let error = error {
               print("Unable to remove document: \(error.localizedDescription)")
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }
}
```

SupplierDetailModelView

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import Combine

class SupplierDetailViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var supplier: SupplierModel
    @Published var modified = false
    
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init(supplier: SupplierModel = SupplierModel(id: "", supplier: "")) {
        self.supplier = supplier
        
        self.$supplier
            .dropFirst()
            .sink { [weak self] supplier in
                self?.modified = true
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    
    func addSupplier(supplier: SupplierModel){
        do {
            let _ = try db.collection("suppliers").addDocument(from: supplier)
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
    private func updateSupplier(_ supplier: SupplierModel) {
       if let documentId = supplier.id {
         do {
           try db.collection("suppliers").document(documentId).setData(from: supplier)
         }
         catch {
           print(error)
         }
       }
     }
    
    private func updateOrAddSupplier() {
        if let _ = supplier.id {
          self.updateSupplier(self.supplier)
        }
        else {
            addSupplier(supplier: supplier)
        }
      }
    
    private func removeSupplier() {
      if let documentId = supplier.id {
        db.collection("supplier").document(documentId).delete { error in
          if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
    func handleDoneTapped() {
      self.updateOrAddSupplier()
    }
    
    func handleDeleteTapped() {
      self.removeSupplier()
    }
    
    func saveSupplier(){
        addSupplier(supplier: supplier)
    }

}
```

Comment: It is not clear to me, after reading this, what the specific question is.

Comment: maybe helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63088521/firebase-and-swiftui-listening-for-real-time-update-strange-behave-weird/63097843#63097843

Comment: @jnpdx sorry for the lack of clarity. How do I create a subcollection of brands onto my suppliers using firestore and swiftUI?

Comment: That is a LOT of code for us to parse through. Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As far as subcollections go, why do you need a subcollection - why not just a collection? A supplier has brands but many suppliers have brands so why not have brands be a top level collection? Models sounds high level as well. The brand Chevrolet has models of cars (documents). But then there are colors and sizes of those models which sound like properties of each model. Can you *shorten* and clarify the question?

Comment: @Jay I would like to create a subcollection to be able to create a supplier which has brands which has colors,  sizes, which are in turn linked to invoice numbers. So by reading into subcollections in firestore, I found out that creating a collection for a supplier and then a subcollection for brands which has models, colours, sizes, etc, would be the best way to go. Are you saying that collection would be enough to cover all of this? If so do you have documentation that can help me with this? I apologize for the lack of clarity in my question.

Comment: It's not clear what the use case is for a "subcollection"; subcollections are typically collections associated with a "parent" document, like a series of dynamic messages that are related to a specific message room (document). In your context, a supplier it not related to any parent object, it is the parent object - they supply things to different clients. Each thing they supply has different properties such as brand, model, color, size etc and those (to me) all sound like fields within a document that makes that thing unique. Just talking out-loud here and I may not fully understand.

Comment: @Jay I think you understood very well and I'll try to simply add a document within one to see if that works for me.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't read any of your code because it's just too much to go through but if you want to create a sub collection within a document this is what you do:

```
func addBrandToSupplier(brand: Brand, supplier: Supplier) {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let newDocumentReference = db.collection("suppliers")
                                 .document(supplier.id)
                                 .collection("brands")
                                 .document()
    
    // If you just put .collection("xyz") after a document Firestore creates a new collection within that document for you.
    // Now I populate that collection with a document to officially create it assuming Brand and Supplier conform to Codable
    try? newDocumentReference.setData(from: brand) { error in
         if error != nil { // Error handling code }
    }
}
```

If you want your view to update after this just simply wrap this function within a `struct` called `SomeViewModel` ("Some" being replaced by whatever you want of course). After that have it add a snapshot listener to the collection and update a `@Published` property. This will now cause your Views to react to the newly created collection.

If this is not what you wanted let me know in the comments and I'll answer your question better.

Comment: @rayaataneja A little late on my reply but this is what I need. Thank you very much!